# pandas.groupby().plot() stacking amount of rows per group by, not actual values

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked bar-graph which shows two transaction types for a customer. The graph is sorted into columns by week.
Sample code within my code structure is below:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
values = [('1','2019-07-28','retail',11),
          ('1','2019-07-28','wholesale',18),
          ('1','2019-08-04','retail',7),
          ('1','2019-08-04','wholesale',12),
          ('1','2019-08-11','retail',6),
          ('1','2019-08-11','wholesale',16)]

columns = ['customer_id','week',
           'transaction_type',
           'sale_count']

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=columns)

df.groupby(['week','transaction_type']).size()\
  .unstack()\
  .plot(sort_columns='week',
        kind='bar', stacked=True);
```

The result I'm getting is a row count for each transaction_type as either 1 or 2

current: 
[image: result_im_currently_getting]

What I need is a stacked bar graph that gives the sum of sale_count for each date listed in week like the one below

expected:

[image: result_im_trying_to_get]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I suppose you want the sum of sales and not the count. So just replace `.count()` with `.sum()`

Answer (score 2):

Similar to commented:

```
(df.groupby(['week','transaction_type'])['sale_count']
   .sum().unstack('transaction_type')
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Quang Hoang's answer is correct and should be accepted and upvoted. This is just a note about formatting code. I guess it will be better to get rid of extra round brackets and move legend outside as in the following code

```py
df.groupby(['week','transaction_type'])['sale_count']\
   .sum().unstack('transaction_type')\
   .plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0)\
   .legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 1.0));
```

[image]